# Editing nodes of a particular content type always times out and wipes out field data on the first try

Tags: nodes

Using Drupal 6.24.

So I have 2 custom content types that are almost identical set for making blog posts and news entries (essentially content for separate but similar blogs). Lately every time we need to edit one of these nodes after its creation, the save process always times out and, while the node body content is generally updated just fine in the process, all the custom field data for that node gets wiped out and we have to scramble to put it back. This doesn't happen for any other content types that we know of so far, and luckily the timeout generally only happens the first and maybe second time we try to edit a particular node at the time so we can still fix everything and make our edits eventually.

Any idea what might cause this and how to stop it?

Comment: is it on hosting server or local staging server? Have you tried increasing the php max_execution_time value? How long exactly does it take before it times out? Can you see anything in your "Recent log entries" related to this?

Comment: Only seems to be on the production site, though both it and the staging have the same php max_execution_time value set (360000). The recent log entries don't show anything for the timeout updates even though the actual body content was updated, just for the eventual fix save a few minutes later.

Comment: Did you check your database integrity ? Sometimes tables get on "crash" state. A simple repair through PhpMyAdmin or command line does the trick. At lest it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I re-cloned the production site's DB and filesystem on the staging server, ran a check and repair there with seemingly no problems, and the problem I'm having still didn't occur there. But after transferring that DB back the production site's still timing out and wiping the CCK and taxonomy fields...